# How to set indent spacing of a tree in libGDX scene2d?

Tags: libgdx, tree, scene2d

I've been trying to create a customized UI using scene2d library in libGDX. However I am having troubles as I'm trying to set a custom indent spacing on my Tree object.

I have tried to search for the answer but haven't actually found any discussions about this on the internet.

[image: Here is how the tree looks now]

This is the current situation which I am having.

[image: This is what it should look]

This is how I would prefer it to look like.

All I want is that I could be able to change the size of the margin which is caused by nodes being on different levels. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the nodes are just `Actor`s, you could place you node content (the labels and sliders) first in some container like `Table` or `Container` and give the actual content a bit of margin in that wrapper container.

After you explanation about what you want to achieve the above won't work as you want to move the *plus* and *minus* buttons that are used to expand and collapse the `Tree`'s `Tree.Node`s.

I don't think the **Scene2D** `Tree` implementation will allow you to set the indentation level to be anything other than the max of the width of the *plus* and the *minus* `Drawable`s. 
But there are always ways around that. The bad news is that the field you need to alter is a private field so simply inheriting `Tree` won't allow you to fix it, but if you're willing to get a bit dirty you can achieve what you're looking for using some reflection.

Instead of doing something like this

```
Tree tree = new Tree(skin);

// Add nodes to tree here
```

You could do this;

```
// First create an instance of Tree where the setStyle method is overridden
tree = new Tree(skin) {
    @Override
    public void setStyle(TreeStyle style) {
        super.setStyle(style);

        // After having called the base class's setStyle, 
        // use horrible reflection to find and alter the indentSpacing field.
        try {
            Field field = Tree.class.getDeclaredField("indentSpacing");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, 8); // This is how much you want each plus and minus indented.
                                // Normally this is set to something like
                                //     Math.max(style.plus.getMinWidth(), style.minus.getMinWidth())
            System.out.println(field);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

// You will likely want to play around with this to make sure the node
// content is not rendered too close to the plus/minus    
tree.setIconSpacing(4, 4);

// Add tree nodes here!
```

This is obviously not ideal, but will likely be easier than creating a new version of `Tree` and get the pull request accepted. Only good thing about this approach is that it involves almost no typing for you.

Alternatively you can just copy the `Tree` code and change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've done some testing but it seems like this is a little bit trickier problem. I think the `Tree` creates it's own containers for every node, so it's impossible to "reach out" those boundaries without accessing and changing the way `Tree` creates and sets those node boundaries.

Comment: @Zigur Ah, you want to indent not just the content of the node, but the *plus* and *minus* buttons as well?

Comment: I think so yes. I did some photoshopping and updated the question to include a visual example of what it should look like.

Comment: @Zigur Right, I've added a horrible thing that will achieve the screenshot you've added. Don't say I didn't warn you though :)

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what I was going for! Guess this is the "cleanest" solution available at the moment. :)